# How can I make the whole page stay where it is?

Tags: html, css

I would like to get a horizontal scroll bar involved when my page hits its breaking point and elements start to escape their divs. I set my header as an inline background image but... well you know, it stays where it is of course and moves out side the div. there is no response when the window gets too small. Help!

```
#logo { 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position: top center; 
    background-size: 100%; 
} 

#mainnavi { 
    border-top:inset gold 3px; 
    background-color:#000033; 
    border-bottom:inset gold 3px; 
    height:45px; text-align:center; 
    font-size:13px; 
    width:100%; 
    text-shadow:20%; 
}   

a:link,a:visited { 
    font-weight:bold; 
    display:inline-block; 
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    background-color:#000033; 
    text-align:center; 
    height:30px; 
    width:120px; 
    text-decoration:blink; 
    overflow:hidden; 
} 
a:hover,a:active { 
    background-color:#000099;
}
```

that is what i have going on for the navigation and my logo.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying here. Can you please provide some code samples? Basically: are you trying to achieve that when the content is too much for the browser window, instead of a vertical scrollbar, it should put your content to the right for example?

Comment: can you elaborate more with code as well?

Comment: #logo {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#mainnavi {
border-top:inset gold 3px;
background-color:#000033;
border-bottom:inset gold 3px;
height:45px;
text-align:center;
font-size:13px;
width:100%;
text-shadow:20%;
}

a:link,a:visited {
font-weight:bold;
display:inline-block;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#000033;
text-align:center;
height:30px;
width:120px;
text-decoration:blink;
overflow:hidden;
}
a:hover,a:active {
background-color:#000099;
}